# babel-preset-react-app, is importing the "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object" package without declaring it in its dependencies

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, babeljs, ejs

My issue is that I've tried to create a new React project and after a lot of issues with vulnerabilities, I managed to solve some of them, one of the main instructions was adding this line:

```
"overrides": {
    "@svgr/webpack": "$@svgr/webpack"
  },
```

into my [package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json/) file.

Once I've done that, I had to delete my [node_modules folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63294260/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-node-modules-folder) folder and reuse `npm install` and now I am getting a [Babel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babel_(transcompiler)) error after typing `npm start`.

```
One of your dependencies, babel-preset-react-app, is importing the
"@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object" package without
declaring it in its dependencies. This is currently working because
"@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object" is already in your
node_modules folder for unrelated reasons, but it may break at any time.

babel-preset-react-app is part of the create-react-app project, which is not maintained anymore. It is thus unlikely that this bug will
ever be fixed. Add "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object" to
your devDependencies to work around this error. This will make this message
go away.
```

I tried to search for the solution over the internet and I found only one that tells me to add this plugin to my devDependencies which did not work, and I also found a solution that tells to type `CI= npm run build`  which didn't work either.

This is what I'm encountering when typing `npm list @babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object`:

```
npm ERR! code ELSPROBLEMS
npm ERR! invalid: @babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object@7.21.0-placeholder-for-preset-env.2 C:\Users\Omri-PC\Desktop\KeeperApp\node_modules\@babel\plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object
keeper-app-part-1-starting@1.0.0 C:\Users\Omri-PC\Desktop\KeeperApp
├── @babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object@7.21.0-placeholder-for-preset-env.2 invalid: "^x.x.x" from the root project
└─┬ @svgr/webpack@8.0.1 overridden
  └─┬ @babel/preset-env@7.22.5
    └── @babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object@7.21.0-placeholder-for-preset-env.2 deduped invalid: "^x.x.x" from the root project
```

And that's how my package.json file looks like if it somehow helps to figure:

```
{
  "name": "keeper-app-part-1-starting",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "keywords": [],
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@svgr/webpack": "^8.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "typescript": "5.1.3"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "@svgr/webpack": "$@svgr/webpack"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

Comment: ELSPROBLEMS mans that npm detects that the node_modules folder has an invalid layout. Could you try adding the devDependency, deleting node_modules and package-lock.json, and re-running npm install?

Answer (score 183):

Running the below command solved my issue

`npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object`

use --save-dev to install it under devDependencies

Comment: Running this command as supplied also fixed my repo. Annoyingly, I had seen numerous "just add it to the dev dependencies" comments with no instructions how to do that. Thanks.

Comment: This fixed my netlify build failure, which treats warnings as errors and fails the build.

Answer (score 27):

Thanks to all, eventually that's what solved my problem:
`npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object --legacy-peer-deps`

Comment: What is your reasoning for adding the --legacy-peer-deps flag?

Answer (score 8):

I also faced this issue today.
I solved by adding the required lib from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object) after that "**npm start**" and "**npm run build**" are fine for me.
Note: used version number **^7.21.11**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 6):

If you prefer `yarn`, this is the equivalent command:

```
yarn add @babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object --dev
```

Answer (score 5):

I tried to add `"@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.21.11"` to devDependencies, and my `CI=npm run build` was successfully completed.

Comment: **Hint:** Add it into the `dependencies: { ... }` section of project's `package.json` file.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a combination of **babel packages** that worked for me:

```json
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.22.5",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "7.22.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "7.21.11",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.22.5",
}
```

**IMPORTANT STEP:** Add `@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object` to **.babelrc plugins** as well. Something like this:

```json
"plugins": [
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object", { "loose": true }]
]
```

**See GitHub Issue:**
https://github.com/babel/babel-plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object/issues/1

Answer (score 5):

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object
```

Probably this is being the best method to resolve your issue, also this may install it under `devDependencies`.

**Long answer:**
As the npm error itself is suggesting, installing the required package as `dev-dependency` works and because it is deprecated package, it should be safe.

Answer (score 3):

I was working on a hobby project earlier today and got the same warning. You just have to add the entry for `"@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object"` under the **devDependencies** object with the installed version in your project. You can find the installed version for your project in the following path:

**node_modules/@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object/package.json**

Once you have this version, just update the entry as mentioned above in the main **package.json** file of the project (the one that has the **run** and **test** commands and so on).

Here are the contents of the **package.json** file I modified to get rid of the warning message:

```json
{
  "name": "clothes_shop",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.21.0-placeholder-for-preset-env.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do to suppress the warning, is to open package.json and add

"@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "7.21.11", as described below. That would help you fix the issue.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "7.21.11",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
```

or you can simply run this

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object
```

Note: this would target devDependencies

Answer (score 3):

By adding this line with the specified version, you are telling npm to install version 7.21.11 of the

> @babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object

package as a dependency. This can help fix any issues related to the plugin or suppress related warnings.

**Node**: while installing/building the app one warning came up as:

> npm WARN deprecated
> @babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object@7.21.11: This
> proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this
> plugin is no longer maintained. Please use
> @babel/plugin-transform-private-property-in-object instead.

I recommend to use:

```
"@babel/plugin-transform-private-property-in-object": "^7.21.11"
```

my build was success

After making this change, you should **run npm install** to ensure that the specified version of the package is installed in your project.

Please note that specifying a fixed version like this can help maintain consistency in your project but may require periodic updates to stay up-to-date with the latest package improvements and security updates.

Answer (score 2):

Also just started having this issue today. Added the recommended package to the devDependencies but also having no success.

**Update:** Updating my global yarn install (or maybe whatever your package manager of choice is) appears to fix the issue.

**Follow Up:** This fix worked for my development and host server but not my production node container.

Comment: If you are using Yarn, you might try using `resolutions` (https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/) to force babel-preset-react-app to get the correct version of that dependency.

Comment: I ended up having to switch to pnpm to get production online again after a large outage. Unfortunately yarn has completely lost my faith after yesterday as did react-scripts which is being switched over to Vite.

Answer (score 2):

One of your dependencies, `babel-preset-react-app`, is importing the `@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object` package without declaring it in its dependencies.

This is currently working because `@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object` is already in your `node_modules` folder for unrelated reasons, but it may break at any time.

`babel-preset-react-app` is part of the *create-react-app* project, which is not maintained anymore.

It is thus unlikely that this bug will ever be fixed.

Add `@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object` to your *devDependencies* to work around this error. This will make this message go away.

this command help you to solve this problem:

```bash
npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object --legacy-peer-deps
```

Answer (score 2):

Run this line:

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue and using this solves my issue.
@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object@7.21.11: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-private-property-in-object instead.

Answer (score 2):

### 2024 Solution

Old answers suggest installing a package (plugin-proposal...), but it was renamed, and the 2024 solution is to use the [babel/plugin-transform...] instead.

#### TL;DR:

If you have this (@babel/plugin-proposal-...):

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.16.7", // PROPOSAL 
    ...
  }
```

**Switch to this** (@babel/plugin-transform-...) - Or install if you don't have any

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-transform-private-property-in-object": "^7.23.4", // TRANSFORM 
    ...
  }
```

More info can be found here at Babel/plugin-transform [documentation](https://babeljs.io/docs/babel-plugin-transform-class-properties):

Answer (score 1):

I realized I got this error because I am using Chakra UI, and using the private statement which is not readily available for older browsers.

I installed the package per the instructions here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object
```

Finally, I had to add a Babel file

```
.babelrc

{
"presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
"plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object"]
```

}

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
yarn add --dev @babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object
```

*use --dev to install it under devDependencie*s

> Pls, remember use engine node version >= 16.0.0

Answer (score 0):

I got this message on my Visual Studio Code:

One of your dependencies, babel-preset-react-app, is importing the
"@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object" package without
declaring it in its dependencies. This is currently working, because
"@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object" is already in your [node_modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63294260/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-node-modules-folder) folder for unrelated reasons, but it may break at any time.

To sort this issue simply install what the warning is suggesting, I am using npm so just do:

```
npm i @babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object -D
```

`-D` means that its only for local development.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: If you're using a monorepo you must add the dev dependency to both the React app in question *and* the root `package.json`, not just to the React app.

More fulsome answer: if you have a **monorepo** (I'm using NPM Workspaces but this may apply to other monorepos too), where one of your apps is the React app in question, similar to:

```
├── apps
│   ├── my-express-api
│   │   └── package.json
│   └── my-cra-app
│       └── package.json
├── package.json
└── package-lock.json
```

You'll need to add the `@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object` dev dependency to both your React app *and* the monorepo's root `package.json`, similar to:

```
// add to app
npm i @babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object --save-dev -w my-cra-app

// ... and to root
npm i @babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object --save-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

The following command will help you:

`npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object`

Answer (score 0):

I simply created a ".babelrc.sjon" file on the root of my application and wrote into it:

```
"presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem simply by updating all the dependencies. Apparently, they solved this issue in latest updates.
You can use [**npm-ckeck-updates package**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates) for this matter.
Here is the process:
*npm i npm-check-updates

ncu -u

npm install*
That's it. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```bash
npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-transform-private-property-in-object
```

Since the `@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object` package is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

to solve this issue just do this :

1. delete "node modules" folder
2. also delete `package-lock.json` (but don't delete `package.json`)
3. then in terminal write `npm i`

This will delete all the node modules and will reinstall all from fresh.
just be careful when deleting anything.

This solved my issue with babel

Comment: Someone already made this exact suggestion in the comment section of the question. Also this does not address the actual error the person was having.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35440515)

Answer (score 0):

just add

```json
"@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.16.7"
```

at `dependencies` in `package.json`

I hope your warning will go.

**My Code**

```json
"dependencies": {
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
        "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
        "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.16.7"
},
```

Comment: Thank you for posting but this is out of date.  pls use https://www.npmjs.com/package/@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object

Answer (score 0):

I tried all of the above but nothing worked for me. It turned out that react didn't like that the parent folder for my project had a # in it.
C:\C#\myreactapp It didn't like the naming of the C# folder. I changed the location to C:\MyProjects\myreactapp and the issue was resolved.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

For me, I used:

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-transform-private-property-in-object
```

and that fixed the issue

Comment: This worked after I cleared my local cache and re run the project. https://tooabstractive.com/how-to-tech/how-to-delete-vscode-cached-data-files/#step-6-inside-the-code-folder-cache-and-cacheddata