# Issues with npm start and Installing Packages: Warning about babel-preset-react-app Dependency and Audit Fix Freezes VSCode

Tags: reactjs, npm, dependencies, create-react-app, hadoop-yarn

Whenever I run `npm start` I run into this message:

```bash
One of your dependencies, babel-preset-react-app, is importing the
"@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object" package without
declaring it in its dependencies. This is currently working because
"@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object" is already in your
node_modules folder for unrelated reasons, but it may break at any time.

babel-preset-react-app is part of the create-react-app project, which
is not maintianed anymore. It is thus unlikely that this bug will
ever be fixed. Add "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object" to
your devDependencies to work around this error. This will make this message
go away.
```

However, I can run `npm start` and view on my local browser.
The issue is not only this yellow warning message is annoying but also, whatever I try to install through terminal,
I just gets lots of errors and warnings.
I can't even install bootstrap or fontawesome with command.

And it recommend me to run some fix command but 100% of running the `audit fix`- kinda code makes it only worse.
Either getting lots of errors and have red screen, or my VScode is frozen without completing fixing stuff.

I had to restart my laptop. :(

**This is my `package.json`, just in case:**

```
{
  "name": "devsimple",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Anybody knows what to do? Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar issue.

npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object --legacy-peer-deps

worked for me

Refer to the following link for solution
[babel-preset-react-app, is importing the "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object" package without declaring it in its dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76435306/babel-preset-react-app-is-importing-the-babel-plugin-proposal-private-propert)